# WIFI printer, network security

Tags: windows-7, security, printer

I have two printers that were connected using the WPS method. I want them to be security restricted but I am unable to stop them being accessed by other people on the network.

The computers are all setup using the standard Windows settings with user names and the default workgroup. I have tried on my laptop to specify security and turn off sharing on the printers but I think because the settings are not setup on the printer that it's only local to my PC.

How can I limit the printer so that only I can print from my PC and prevent people finding and adding it from the network?

The printers are [Canon Ip7250](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_ip_series/pixma_ip7220) and also [Canon Pro-100](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/office/products/hardware/printers/inkjet/pixma/pixma_pro-100/).

Comment: I think the most simple way is under your network printer management page, disable the network discovery function Unless the user know the printer's IP or hostname, he can't simply find the printer via `network`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your consumer printers are not likely to support authentication / authorization. So your recourse is to limit the access to the printers.

If you have an advanced Switch that supports access-list, you can limit the communication of your printers to your PC only.

Another way is to move the printers to a private network which only your PC can access. You will need to setup your router such that it will route between your PC and the printer. This also requires that your printer does not assume its clients are on the same LAN.

A less protected way is that you can assign your printer a static IP (e.g. 10.2.3.4) that is not on the same subnet as its LAN (e.g. 192.168.x.x). And then, you can add a secondary IP address to your PC (e.g. 10.2.3.1). Your PC and printers can continue to communicate via this pseudo LAN while other users cannot unless they also add a secondary IP and subnet.